# Get All Images Without Zip With Nextgen Download Gallery images

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I have a wordpress website which is using the Nextgen gallery.This site is having various catalog on homepage containing various product images and details. I have a button in catalog page on each catalog. On clicking on this button, all the images inside the catalog is downloading, but it is downloading in zip format. I want the URL of the images of the product inside it.

Comment: What You have try yet ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Kindly see this and let me know if you can help [posted question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110122/download-all-images-nextgen-gallery-wordpress)